# Toggle menu left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried making a menu that toggles left to right and I copied some of the script from the suggestion on this post: http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1/
however, when I plug in my specific Class and Id names, I didn't seem to work. The menu will open up but it doesn't seem to want to close. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('.menuBars').click(function () {
if($('.menuBars').is(':visible')){
    $('.menuBars').fadeOut(function () {
    $('.menuItems').toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 1000);
});
}
else{
    $('.menuItems').toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 1000, function() { $('.menuBars').fadeIn();});
}
});
```

This is my CCS:

```
.menuItems {
position:relative;
float: right;
display:none;
top: 50%;
margin-top:-9px;
background-color:#DEDEDE;
border-radius:4px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;}
```

and my HTML:

```
    <div class="nav">
    <div id="name">
        <p>Richard</p></div>
   <div class="menuBars">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>

   <div class="menuItems">
        <ul>
            <li id="closer"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed a small part while applying your classes, the click event should be applied to both `.menuBars`  and `.menuItems`. This has to be done cause  when the menu is shown and the title is hidden you can't click on the title, you click on the menu and this should trigger the slide and the fade.

Simply correct the function to be:

```
$('.menuBars, .menuItems').click(function () {
```

This should solve your problem
http://jsfiddle.net/wf0fpzy6/

Comment: But wouldn't that make it so that clicking anywhere on the .menuItems would close the slide menu as opposed to a dedicated button (like an 'X') to close the slide menu? I made a closing icon but when I select the div ID containing my close icon, nothing happens.

Comment: This how the original fiddle in your example worked. ِAnd it should work if the closing icon is in the `.menuItems` div. And your question is answered please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, your code occurs `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function` error.

You need to include [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) for the extended easing options.

and your div will not close, because close button has no any event for that.

**Fixed code**

```
$(function() {
  $('#closer').click(function () {
    $('.menuBars').fadeIn(function () {
      $('.menuItems').toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
  $('.menuBars').click(function(){
   $('.menuItems').toggle('slide', {
          direction: 'left'
      }, 1000, function() { $('.menuBars').fadeOut();});
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d77z00jg/4/)**

Comment: Ah, ok. I linked jQuery UI and that made the easing and buttons work. Thanks! 
But now the sliding menu slides out above the menu button then moves down once the menu button disappears. Does that have to do with my element layering or am I missing some rule?

Comment: I just noticed the menu hops on Fiddle too, menu opens above menu button  then move to where the menu button used to be once the menu button disappears. Thanks for all the help!